# Visual studio code debug Angular with custom localhost

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

I've initialized a blank angular project with `ng new` and configured the launch.json in visual studio code with default chrome launch

```
"configurations": [
{
"type": "chrome",
"request": "launch",
"name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
"url": "http://localhost-app.myapp.com:4200",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
]
```

I've mapped in my host file 127.0.0.1 to this custom url and modified in `package.json` the start script with

```
"start": "ng serve --disable-host-check",
```

application work calling custom URL but VSC debugger **does not bind breakpoints**.

If I set `localhost` in launch.json and remove `--disable-host-check`, debugger works as usual launched on localhost.

Is there any way to make VSC debugger work on `localhost-app.myapp.com` my custom host?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Accepted answer didn't help me, I couldn't find a vs code proxy configuration.

Comment: In my case the issue was proxy configuration. I found the problem when I open "DEBUG CONSOLE", debugger cannot connect to browser because it tries to pass throgh proxy, have you checked this tab?

Comment: Debug console got me closer, but still having issues. My setup is a little different so I can't quite get it, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps, I solve my problem removing vs code proxy configuration.

Proxy blocks source map discovery and does not load sourcemaps.

So, check your proxy conf if you have one

Answer (score -1):

The launch.json file should look like this, with values changed to reflect your environment:

```
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
                "url": "http://localhost:4200",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            {
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "attach",
                "name": "Attach to Chrome",
                "port": 9222,
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        ]
```

You can reffer to more info here:

https://automationpanda.com/2018/01/12/debugging-angular-apps-through-visual-studio-code/

Comment: it works for localhost, but if use another local domain like localhost-app.myapp.com it does not work